# how to convert date YYYYMMDDHHmm to YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm format in linux

Tags: xml, awk

I have xml file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<programme start="20160813000000" stop="20160813003000">
   <category lang="en">News</category>
 </programme>
 <programme start="20160813003000" stop="20160813010000">
   <category lang="en">TV Show</category>
 </programme>
 <programme start="20160813010000" stop="20160813060000">
   <category lang="en">Sports</category>
 </programme>
 </xml>
```

how to convert start and stop datetime format to YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm using linux batch file?

Comment: If you have a choice, please consider using the ISO 8601 date format `YYYY-MM-DD` rather than `YYYY/MM/DD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a job for sed rather than awk since sed is the best tool for simple substitutions on individual lines (awk is for everything else):

```
$ sed -E 's,((start|stop)="....)(..)(..)(..)(..)..",\1/\3/\4 \5:\6",g' file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<programme start="2016/08/13 00:00" stop="2016/08/13 00:30">
   <category lang="en">News</category>
 </programme>
 <programme start="2016/08/13 00:30" stop="2016/08/13 01:00">
   <category lang="en">TV Show</category>
 </programme>
 <programme start="2016/08/13 01:00" stop="2016/08/13 06:00">
   <category lang="en">Sports</category>
 </programme>
 </xml>
```

and if you wanted to keep the seconds too it's obviously just a tweak to include them in a capture group:

```
$ sed -E 's,((start|stop)="....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(.."),\1/\3/\4 \5:\6:\7,g' file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<programme start="2016/08/13 00:00:00" stop="2016/08/13 00:30:00">
   <category lang="en">News</category>
 </programme>
 <programme start="2016/08/13 00:30:00" stop="2016/08/13 01:00:00">
   <category lang="en">TV Show</category>
 </programme>
 <programme start="2016/08/13 01:00:00" stop="2016/08/13 06:00:00">
   <category lang="en">Sports</category>
 </programme>
 </xml>
```

Comment: This is more readable as you used `(..)` instead of `[0-9]{2}` as I did. I dont think `start=""` will have non-numerical values anyways, but just didnt want to assume it.  Interestingly the `man page ` for sed that I have had never shown me `-E` option so I've always used `-r` for ERE. But i tried with `-E` like you did and it worked. Maybe its a man page issue. My sed is `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2` and man page is also for same version.

Comment: @sps - `-E` is non-standard FreeBSD extension. But recent versions of `GNU sed` seems to silently support `-E`.

Comment: @sps, @altvis is right. `-r` will only work with GNU sed but `-E` will work with BSD sed and (undocumentedly) with newer GNU sed versions so IMHO `-E` is the way to go as it's more portable. It really was ridiculous that GNU grep used `-E` to enable EREs but GNU sed used `-r`!

Answer (score 1):

`sed` can be used to do text transformation like this.

You can use:

```
sed 's@\(start="\|stop="\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)@\1\2/\3/\4 \5:\6:\7@g' filename
```

Above command is very hard to read and maintain. However many backslashes in the above command canbe avoided if extended regex option `-r` is used.

```
sed -r 's@(start="|stop=")([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})@\1\2/\3/\4 \5:\6:\7@g' filename
```

Both the above comands will only print the output without changing the original file, so you may need to redirect the ouput to a newfile if you need.

However if you want to modify the orriginal file itself, then you need to use `-i` option, like:

```
sed -i 'command' filename
```

Finally, if you want to create a backup of the origianl file before modifying - just in case - you can do:

```
sed -i.bak 'command' filename
```

Comment: FYI on BSD sed you NEED to proved an argument to `-i`, even if it's just `""`, or it'll take `'command'` as that backup file name instead of the script you want to execute.

Comment: @EdMorton Thats a useful info.

Answer (score 0):

Use "date -j -f" command. For example:

```
date -j -f "%Y%m%d" "27 JUN 2011" +%Y/%m/%d
```